# How to change the Windows font folder?

Tags: c#, fonts, path

So [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407702/how-to-get-the-path-to-the-windows-fonts-folder) covers nicely how to get the current font path, but what if I want to change the path?

For example, currently

`System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts);`

would contain something like

> C:\Windows\Fonts

but what if for the purposes of this project I want it to point to

> D:\Resources\Fonts

Is there a way I can do that? Or a way to tell Windows not to use its Environment path and instead use the path I want?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to accomplish? That sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: You really, really DONT want to do this.

Comment: We have some custom fonts already installed on the system in a resource folder. We are going through a major overhaul of the system which involved moving lots of code that used to be done with script files into c#. This is where the font issue comes into play. I have been asked to avoid moving the fonts if possible. If it is not possible I need to make a case for it.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to change system settings. You can load the fonts from whichever folder you like. For example:

```
var pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();
pfc.AddFontFile(fontFile);

var fontFamily = new FontFamily(pfc.Families.First().Name,pfc);

richTextBox1.Font = new Font(fontFamily, 20f, FontStyle.Bold);
richTextBox1.Text = "Test";
```

Comment: PrivateFontCollection is part of the System.Drawing assembly right? Is there any other way to do this? Drawing is not currently one of the Assemblies I have access to (though I might be able to change that given a good enough reason or proof there is no other way).